# PHP encryption and URLs issue, help?

Tags: php, url, encryption

I made an encrypt/decrypt methods that base on this model

```
// encrypt:
base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key),
$string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))))

//decrypt:
rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key),
base64_decode($encrypted), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))), "\0");
```

it all works well inside the same page, so that

```
decrypt(encrypt ('hello',$key))
```

works well, 
but when I send the link:

```
echo "http://link.here?data=".urlencode(encrypt(('hello',$key)));
```

on the other receiving page I:

```
decrypt(urldecode($_GET['data']),$key));
```

I get a mess.

I notice that there is something VERY weird happening to the decrypted message.

I encrpyt '72', then read it back and decrypt it.
I noticed something very weird was happening when I tested it with `is_numeric()`... It didn't respond to either true nor false !! something weird was going on....
So I tested with `strlen`, and the result was... 4 !
I figured something somehow happened with the bytes, but I have NO idea what it may be.
I am trying to pass a number through an email body, and I am trying to make it work,
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: does mb_strlen return 4 also?

Comment: Tried it with '123456' I get 8 in response to either mb_strlen and strlen as well

Comment: Stupid question, but are you sure you're using the same `$key` between the two pages? I tried your code and it worked just fine (apart from the `urldecode`, but you say you've tried without it).

Comment: Unrelated comment: `rtrim` already trims NUL bytes, no need to pass `"\0"`.

Comment: I just noticed these were leading and closing spaces. trim fixed that, for now at least. Thanks for the help !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try taking the `urldecode` out of the code on your receiving page.

Unless you've got double-encoding going on somewhere (and there's no sign of that in what you've posted), you don't need (or want) to `urldecode` strings from `$_GET`. PHP does this for you.

For "text-only" data, `urldecoding` too many times *can* end up being harmless. However, in your specific case, where the underlying text is Base64, it's very likely to be harmful, since `urldecode` converts `+` signs (which are one of the characters used in Base64) to spaces.

Comment: I am not urldecoding, but I am urlencoding. Though, why is strlen 4 ? should be 2... php is weird about it, what are those 2 extra bytes, and how come I can read it as the string '72' ?

Comment: I'm confused: you posted that your receiving-side code was `decrypt(urldecode($_GET['data']),$key));`, and that's the equivalent of two `urldecode` passes.

Comment: I tried it with and without, makes no apparent difference, sorry for the confusion

Comment: I thought maybe if I  just convert that to a number it could work, but then, realized that if someone planted "2fsdfsdf" it would translate as 2, which is not ok.

Comment: I think I solved it. I went through the bytes of the array, and saw there were leading spaces there. I just trim the result and for now it seems like doing it. Thank you !